# How to properly StartTime and StopTime in golang benchmark?

Tags: testing, go, benchmarking

I wrote a benchmark to test the speed of two Fibonacci number generators, and the source code is [here on github](https://github.com/nosarthur/dp/blob/master/fibonacci/fib_test.go).

```
func BenchmarkFib(b *testing.B) {
    fibFuncs := []struct {
        name string
        f    func(int) int
    }{
        {"recursive", fibRecu},
        {"iterative", fibIter},
    }
    for _, fibFunc := range fibFuncs {
        // calculate k'th Fibonacci number
        for k := 10; k < 1001; k *= 10 {
            b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("%s Fib %v", fibFunc.name, k), func(b *testing.B) {
                for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
                    //                  b.StopTimer()
                    // reset the memo
                    memo = map[int]int{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1}
                    //                  b.StartTimer()
                    fibFunc.f(k)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

As it is, the benchmark works and the output is

```
nos (master) fibonacci $ go test -bench .
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/nosarthur/dynamicP/fibonacci
BenchmarkFib/recursive_Fib_10-4                  1000000              1256 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/recursive_Fib_100-4                  100000             18256 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/recursive_Fib_1000-4                  10000            206109 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/iterative_Fib_10-4                 10000000               218 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/iterative_Fib_100-4                 5000000               292 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/iterative_Fib_1000-4                2000000               881 ns/op
PASS
ok      github.com/nosarthur/dynamicP/fibonacci 12.208s
```

However, I added `b.StopTime()` and `b.StartTime()` to exclude the time for resetting the memo. With these two lines un-commented, the benchmark hangs, and the partial output is

```
nos (master *) fibonacci $ go test -bench .
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/nosarthur/dynamicP/fibonacci
BenchmarkFib/recursive_Fib_10-4                  1000000              2139 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/recursive_Fib_100-4                  100000             24775 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/recursive_Fib_1000-4                   5000            239197 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/iterative_Fib_10-4                 ^Csignal: interrupt
FAIL    github.com/nosarthur/dynamicP/fibonacci 269.067s
```

What is the proper way to exclude the memo resetting? My go version is 1.10.1

Comment: Your code is not correct. You say that `The 93'th Fibonacci number is : -6246583658587674878.` Overflow!

Comment: Not sure, but the k loop outside of b.Run looks fishy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that your functions are **really** fast, particularly in the case of the iterative function, and your map reset (as well as the `StartTimer` and `StopTimer` functions themselves with the runtime stat allocation) are much, much slower.

So what's happening is that when you call `StopTimer` it's setting the internally tracked duration of the benchmark to only the time it took to run the function. Well guess how it estimates how many iterations to run within the designated benchmark time? Yep, you guessed it - the internal duration.

So basically, your iterative function takes about 10ns to run, the map reset takes about 250ns, and the Timer functions take considerably longer - but the benchmark is estimating that each run takes only 20ns and is setting the number of iterations accordingly.

My suggestion - don't use the `StartTimer/StopTimer` functions in this case, and simply add a third run to your tests that's a non-op -- basically:

```
{"baseline", func(int) int {return 0}},
```

Then just subtract the times from this function from the other two sets to estimate how much of the ns/op was from the allocation vs the functions themselves.

Here's the results when I ran this:

```
BenchmarkFib/baseline_Fib_10-2           5000000           357 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/baseline_Fib_100-2          5000000           327 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/baseline_Fib_1000-2         5000000           310 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/recursive_Fib_10-2          1000000          1659 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/recursive_Fib_100-2           50000         24898 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/recursive_Fib_1000-2           5000        301771 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/iterative_Fib_10-2          5000000           333 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/iterative_Fib_100-2         3000000           394 ns/op
BenchmarkFib/iterative_Fib_1000-2        1000000          1052 ns/op
PASS
ok      _/tmp/dynamicP/fibonacci    15.305s
```